# locate outputs question marks when locatedb contains certain characters (tabs) unless output is piped

Tags: terminal, tty, locate, ascii

I construct my own `locatedb` using `frcode` so it would contain filesizes after paths (it helps me look for large files quickly). I store the path separated from the size by a tab character. I've noticed that if I use locate in the command-line, I get a `?` (question mark) where the tab should be, *unless I pipe it to* `cat`, which is weird. Does anybody know why this is?

```
$ mkdir test-locatedb && cd test-locatedb
$ touch a b c d e f g
$ du -a | awk -v 'OFS=\t' '{print $2,$1}' | /path/to/frcode > test.locatedb
$ locate --database=test.locatedb a
./test.locatedb?1
./a?1
$ locate --database=test.locatedb a | cat
./a     1
./test.locatedb 1    
$ /usr/lib/locate/frcode -v
frcode (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that this is coded into `locate` by checking if output is `stdout` or not. And indeed, `locate` has a condition to replace non-printable characters with question marks when output is a tty (see [`printquoted.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/printquoted.c?h=FINDUTILS_4_4_2-1&id=875bfec31fc71515507a05a19f38f443bd868220) and [`qmark.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/qmark.c?h=FINDUTILS_4_4_2-1&id=875bfec31fc71515507a05a19f38f443bd868220)). It considers whitespace in the ASCII control character range to be non-printable as well. I think this is unfortunate, as one would not expect output to the terminal to change when piping through `cat`.  This is true for `findutils` 4.6.0 as well. I submitted a [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49147).